# Averaging numbers in list

Tags: python, function, math, sum, average

Find 5 numbers
Find average of numbers

```
#import statistics
print("enter 5#s")
num1 = int(input())
num2 = int(input())
num3 = int(input())
num4 = int(input())
num5 = int(input())
numbers = [num1, num2, num3, num4, num5]
numsum = sum(numbers)
print("sum is:", numsum)
#Above list is working
#fix below
def Average(numbers):
    return sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
print("AVG = ", round(Average, 2))
```

error
traceback (most recent call last):
file "main.py", line 15 in 
print("AVG = ", round(Average, 2))
TypeError: type function dosent define_round_method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last line (the call to `print`)

```
def Average(numbers):
    return sum(numbers) / len (numbers)
    print("AVG = ", round(Average, 2))
```

needs to be un-indented (moved to the left, outside of the function) and the function needs to be called with `numbers` as its argument, like this:

```
def Average(numbers):
    return sum(numbers) / len (numbers)
print("AVG = ", round(Average(numbers), 2))
```

---

Your code could be simplified and improved, maybe like this:

```
num_list = []
for i in range(5):
    s = input('Enter the {}. number: '.format(i+1))
    n = int(s)
    num_list.append(n)

the_sum = sum(num_list)
print('Sum:', the_sum)

the_avg = round(the_sum / len(num_list), 2)
print('Avg:', the_avg)
```

Sample run:

```
Enter the 1. number: 7
Enter the 2. number: 5
Enter the 3. number: 4
Enter the 4. number: 4
Enter the 5. number: 4
Sum: 24
Avg: 4.8
```

Comment: @blackstar I added a few code improvement suggestions, for example, using a loop instead of repeating the same code many times.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extra line at the end, which should be:

```
Average(numbers)
```